# Git PR showing files as modified even though they are unchanged

Tags: git

I've pushed my branch to a repo and made a PR against master. For some reason it's showing a ton of files as being changed in the `Files Changed` section, even though they haven't been changed at all. FWIW, I made sure to `git fetch` and `git merge upstream/master` prior to pushing.

Comment: what are the differences?

Comment: Are you working on different OS's? Might be changes in line breaks.

Comment: No I don't think it's an OS problem. I've made pushes to that repo before and never had an issue. The changes seems to be comparing my current branch with a version of master that is a couple commits ago.

Comment: Could be file permissions as well...

Comment: Well, run `git diff` between your branch and `master`. Maybe something that the UI does not really display all that well... some of the scenarios hinted in previous comments here.

Comment: May you share what the changes are?

Comment: There's quite a lot of changes (203 files in total). They can be viewed here: https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/pull/4978  `git diff` does show the changes, but it won't let me merge because it says everything's up to date.

Comment: If you `git diff -w other_branch` does it still report the same changed files? If it doesn't the changes are likely whitespace differences.

Comment: Yes `git diff master` does report the same changed files

Comment: I bet your settings for git are changing the EOL format of the files. `core.autocrlf` perhaps?